# Show that: $\log^{2019} n = o(n)$

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

That is to find $a,\;c$ and $n$ such that:
$\log^{2019} n = o(n)$

Comment: That is very easy. You know, that the log-function is slower than every polynomial. Based on a concavity argument the statement holds

Comment: @FredJefferson It's known as little-o notation. Basically, $f(n)\in o(g(n))$ (often written as $f(n)=o(g(n))$, but that's abuse of notation) means that $g(n)$ is eventually larger than any constant multiple of $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe below that for all $n>1$,
$$n=n$$
$$n^\frac{1}{2019}=n^\frac{1}{2019}$$
$$\log n^\frac{1}{2019} <n^\frac{1}{2019}$$
$$\frac{1}{2019} \log n <n^\frac{1}{2019}$$
$$\bigg( \frac{1}{2019} \log n \bigg) ^{2019} < (n^\frac{1}{2019})^{2019}$$
$$\bigg( \frac{1}{2019} \bigg)^{2019}( \log n ) ^{2019} < n$$
$$\frac{1}{2019^{2019}}( \log n ) ^{2019} < n$$
$$( \log n ) ^{2019} < 2019^{2019}n$$
$$ \log^{2019} n  < 2019^{2019}n$$

where $2019^{2019} = c \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, by substitution we have

$$\log^{2019} n  < c \cdot n$$

Answer (score 2):

We can see$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{\frac{1}{2019}}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac1x}{\frac{1}{2019}x^{\frac{1}{2019}-1}}=0$$
so$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log^{2019} x}{x}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

For any $c > 0$ and $n > 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
\log(n)
&=\int_1^n \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&=\int_1^n t^{-1}dt\\
&<\int_1^n t^{-1+c}dt\\
&=\dfrac{t^c}{c}|_1^n\\
&=\dfrac{n^c-1}{c}\\
&<\dfrac{n^c}{c}\\
\end{array}
$

Letting $c = a/2$,
$\log(n)
\lt \dfrac{n^{a/2}}{a/2}
= \dfrac{2n^{a/2}}{a}
= n^a\dfrac{2n^{-a/2}}{a}
$
for any $a > 0$.

Putting $a = 1/m$,

$\begin{array}\\
\log(n)
&\lt n^{1/m}(m2n^{-1/(2m)})\\
\text{so}\\
\log^m(n)
&\lt n(m2n^{-1/(2m)})^m\\
&= n((2m)^mn^{-1/2})
\qquad\text{since } (2m)^mn^{-1/2} \to 0\\
&\in o(n)\\
\end{array}
$